# Is there a way to make a discord python bot in 3.6 when admins do the command !start

Tags: python-3.6, discord.py

when this command is active and the other users do !join, it will add them to a list and then when 6 people have joined it randomizes them into 2 teams of 3

```py
import discord
from discord import Game
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import unicodedata
import sys
import time
BOT_PREFIX = ("!")
TOKEN = "token"

client = Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as " + client.user.name)
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name="Making a bot"))

client.loop.create_task(list_servers())
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Sorry, what's the question?  `list_servers` isn't defined, and the code you've written doesn't seem to have anything to do with the text in your question

Comment: Yea seems like he wants us to write a complete code from scratch. Yea we could do that but who has the time for that? This isn't what this site is about. At the very least try to code it yourself and then ask specific question instead of asking for entire code.